# How to unit test a textView using a spy

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, stub, spy

I have a cell that contains a `textView` and i would like to test that the properties of that `textView` are set correctly using unit tests. However i seem to have hit a blocker when it comes to having access to the textView in the test since its private.

**Is there a way I can test my textView**:-

Here is my code

```
class MyCell {

  private let myText: UITextView = {
      let textView = UITextView()
      textView.isScrollEnabled = false
      textView.isEditable = false

      return textView
    }()

  func setup(viewModel: MYViewModel) {

      if viewModel.someValue {
          myText.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      } else {
          myText.backgroundColor = .clear
      }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to test something like the testView's background color is set to clear ?

Comment: Normally, we do not verify UI elements in unit testing. That's the reason XCUITestcase exist. You wanna try this using XCUITestcase?

Comment: great suggestion however in UI testing can i test that the textView's background is set to nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to relax the access level of `myText` from `private` to `internal` (the default if you don't specify it), there is no *direct* way to test it.

The only suggestion I have to test this indirectly would be to use [snapshot testing](https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case).

You could write two snapshot tests, one for each value of `.someValue` from your `MYViewModel`.

Another option to make the testing –and maintainability– of your view straightforward is to introduce a `ViewConfiguration` value type, following the [humble view](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView) pattern.

Basically, you can have a `struct` in between `MYViewModel` and `MyCell` that describes each of the view properties for `MyCell`.

```
struct MyCellViewConfiguration {
  let textFieldBackgroundColor: UIColor
}

extension MYViewModel {

  var viewConfiguration: MyCellViewConfiguration = {
    return MyCellViewConfiguration(
      textFieldBackgroundColor: someValue ? .red : .clear
    )
  }
}

extension MyCell {

  func setup(with configuration: MyCellViewConfiguration) {
    myText.backgroundColor = configuration.textFieldBackgroundColor
  }
}
```

The code in `setup(with configuration: MyCellViewConfiguration)` is so simple –just a 1-to-1 assignment– that you can get away without testing it.

You can then write test for how `MyCellViewConfiguration` is computed from `MYViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `private` from your declaration. Then the access control will be the default `internal`. In the test code, make sure to `@testable import` so gain access to internal features.

Unit testing a few attributes isn't hard. But if you want a test that records the appearance, look into snapshot testing. This can be done without XCUITestCase. It's an order of magnitude slower than a regular unit test, but probably another order of magnitude faster than a UI test.